# How to reset ZURB/Foundation SCSS Style settings

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I found some info on overriding style settings; however, what I'd like to do is not set them at all.

For example, I want *h1* to be in color blue, like so:

```
h1 { color: blue; }
```

I want *h1 a* to have the same color as the surrounding *h1*, like so:

```
h1 { color blue;
    a {/*nothing*/}
}
```

However, I find the following code in my app.css:

```
/* Default Link Styles */
/* line 152, ../../../../../../../../../../../../../usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/zurb-foundation-4.3.2/scss/foundation/components/_type.scss */
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: inherit;
}
```

Now, it doesn't make sense to exclude _type.scss in the app.scss, (if that would even be possible). I want the text-decoration and line-height settings; I just DON'T want the color setting.

The docs just say "*Links are very standard, and the color is preset to the Foundation primary color.*" - Not very useful.

Sadly, I haven't found a way to unset a sass variable either, otherwise I could just unset *$anchor-font-color* and be happy.

So, do I stand any chance of achieving my goal, or do I have to set the color for every possible *XYZ > a* combination manually?

Comment: better create your own `.scss` to override foundation scss file there change the color and styles you needed this is what am doing with `foundation`

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually give a value for `h1 a` to override the style - so use:

```
h1, h1 a { 
    color: blue;
}
```